# Why is "image" in .into red

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

I don't understand why "image" in .into is underlined in red.

I just need the picture to be shown by clicking on the button

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/timHt.png)

```
package com.example.raspisanie

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val image = findViewById<View>(R.id.image)
        val button = findViewById<View>(R.id.button)
        val url = "https://vsegda-pomnim.com/uploads/posts/2022-04/1649143490_6-vsegda-pomnim-com-p-priroda-islandii-foto-8.jpg"
        button.setOnClickListener {
            Glide.with(this)
                .load(url)
                .into(image)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The "red underlining" is your IDE telling you: something is wrong with your code. Hover the mouse over that line, and see the error message you get. Seriously: it seems you are starting from the wrong end. You have to UNDERSTAND how the TOOLS you are using work. It is a really bad idea to learn coding and learning a tool at the same time time. So before going into the depths of kotlin on Android, watch some tutorial videos on your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to type mismatch. The type of image should be ImageView. Change  `val image = findViewById<View>(R.id.image)` to  `val image = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image)`